# Locking/Confirming a selection in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, locking, selection

I'm creating a text based fighting game program with Javascript and jQuery. My jQuery knowledge is basic at the moment (about 1-2 weeks worth).

The fighting game program will have:

- an object function defining character names, hp, and attack-strength
- an object array with stored information of names, hp, etc.
- a player and an enemy (opponent)
- and an attack function connected to an html button

Currently I can port all my characters information (object array) to an html document using .html() and .append(), inside of a for loop, while giving them an (id = "champion[i].name"), and data-sets of their hp, attack-strength, etc. using .attr().

```
for (var i = 0; i < champions.length; i++)  {                                   // the forLoop is to get all the characters in the object array on the screen.
    var champAvailable = $("<button>");                                      // this variable is equal to a button that will soon be ported to the HTML page
        champAvailable.addClass("champ styling hoverAnimation");                // creating what the character buttons looks like
        champAvailable.attr("id", champions[i].name);                           // adding the data for names
        champAvailable.attr("data-hp", champions[i].hitPoints);                 // adding the data for hp 
        champAvailable.attr("data-attPower", champions[i].attPower);            // adding the data for attack power 
        champAvailable.attr("data-icon", champions[i].icon);                    // adding the data for icons
        champAvailable.html(champions[i].icon);                                 // porting the image to the html
        $("#champAvailable").append(champAvailable);                             // checking the html for the id "champBtn" and connecting my champBtn variable to it
                                                                                // .append() will attach each character in my array sequentially.
}
```

from the select screen you can click on the character and it will clone them to the player div section.

```
$(".champ").on("click", function(event){                                        // adding the champ to the selected champ section
        var champSelection = $("<div>");                                        // deciding that I will make the section a new Div
        champSelection.append($(this).clone().addClass("clone").removeClass("hoverAnimation"));  // "this" is equal to the champBtn, which contains the stored data of my champions
                                                                                                    // .clone makes a new icon in the champion div
                                                                                                    // .addClass lets me adjust the clone to look different from the other champion icons
                                                                                                    // removeClass removes the hover animation from the clone
                                                                                                    // without .clone() the image will delete its original position and move it to the champ selection space



        $("#playerChamp").html(champSelection);                                                  // this ports the cloned image to the html

});
```

at this point you can click on any character and it will clone that character to the character selection div, replacing whatever was there before.

Now I want to confirm the selection. 
The method I thought would be best would be a "confirm-select button" in the html doc.

At this point I only have pseudo code and am not sure the best direction to take to make this work.

```
    // Confirm Champ Pseudo Code: selecting the player and the opponent

    // (var playerState = false) as default
    // When the "confirm-selection Champion button" is clicked:
    // (var player = champions[i]) and (var champState = true)
    // -- I'm hoping that the data-sets carry over here and that you don't get every data-set of the champions[i]. Just the one you selected -- //
    // when playerState is true:
    // champions[i] in the champion select section becomes onclick: Null
    // end player selection part. 

    // Champion selection then moves to: Opponent selection
    // (var enemyState = false) as default
    // when "confirm-selection Opponent button" is clicked:
    // (var enemy = champions[i]) and (var enemyState = true) 
    // champions[i] in the champion select section becomes onclick: Null
    // end Opponent selection part
```

There are some issues with this, such as when opponent is defeated they need to keep their onclick: null status, but enemyState will become false again, as a new opponent needs to be picked. I could possibly create a defeated class.

Because of the type of information I need, I'm unable to find answers regarding keywords such as "lock selection", "character selection screen", "choose character", "lock variable", etc. without getting answers to Flash related code and answers regarding the term character(char).

For Javascript/jQuery is there a "confirm" selection function?

If I create an .on("click", function(){}) with an (event) argument:

Would I set (confirmChamp = champions[i]) to store that selection or will that only store the last [i] position from the loop?

Must I give (confirmChamp.attr("data-sets")) or is this data already stored from champAvailable?

Lastly, will setting (confirmChamp.onclick = null) keep the option from being reselected later?

*I also have html code if that is necessary.*

Comment: *"Is this anywhere in the right direction? *" I feel bad, because you've put a lot of work into the question, but that question makes it opinion based, so will lead to close votes.  Maybe just remove that part and make the 3 bullet points clearly questions?

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m. I wasn't aware that could happen. I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

After much research I have found an answer to the question proposed. What you need is create an if statement of booleans.

```
var $champLocked = false;

$('.champ').on('click', function(event){ // when the button champ is clicked                                        

    if ($champLocked === false) { // check if champLocked is false. It is, because we said it is at the top. Now go to the next step.

        var champSelection = $('<div>');    // create your div                                  
        var champInfo = $(this);    // give it its data                                         

        var data = {
            name: champInfo.attr('id'),
            hp: champInfo.data('hp'),
            attack: champInfo.data('attack')    
        }; // fun data .. End of function 1
```

_

```
$('#confirmChamp').on('click', function() { // new button to click

    if(!champLocked) { // same as above, (if champ === false) just written shorter.

        champLocked = true; // we then set it to true
        $(this).prop('onclick',null).off('click'); // we set the onclick button of "this", which is, I believe #confirmChamp, to the property of an onlclick with a null value, and then attached an .off() method to the click.
        }); 
    } // end second functin
```

Now your champ is officially locked from reselect.